# htaccess Redirect Error Page

Tags: .htaccess

I know this is a common question but I am not sure why this is failing on my localhost (WAMP).

I would like to redirect a 500 error to my login page. I have tried the following:

- `ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/mysite/login.php`
- `ErrorDocument 500 C:/wamp64/www/mysite/login.php`
- `ErrorDocument 500 mysite/login.php`
- `ErrorDocument 500 login.php`

Each of these have failed to redirect to my login page.

Comment: What exactly is happening?

Comment: I was testing something in PHP. I wanted to confirm what would happen if I disabled error reporting. As expected I got a `500 error`. I would like to configure a redirect for this with `htaccess`

Comment: A 500 error triggered by PHP won't trigger the Apache error document.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for the reply, I believe you but could you possibly point to some documentation on that?

Answer (score 0):

> I was testing something in PHP. I wanted to confirm what would happen if I disabled error reporting. As expected I got a 500 error. I would like to configure a redirect for this with htaccess

You can't define an ErrorDocument in `.htaccess` to handle this.

PHP itself will return an empty 500 response when `display_errors` is off and an unrecoverable error occurs in your application.

To customise/handle this response you need to define your own custom PHP error handler.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

(But note that if you have a fatal *parse error* in your script then your error handler probably still won't be called - but that should never happen on a production server.)

> could you possibly point to some documentation on that?

I don't have a central point of reference for this, unfortunately. It's really just the way it works...

The Apache ErrorDocument is only triggered when Apache itself triggers the error response. (Although a custom 500 ErrorDocument won't be triggered for *all* Apache 500 responses and with it defined late in `.htaccess` it probably won't catch much at all. This should be defined in the server config / virtual host.)

For the Apache ErrorDocument to be triggered when PHP has sent a response, Apache would need to intercept and override the response - that does not happen. In the same way you might send a 404 from your PHP script, Apache does not intercept this to send the Apache 404 response.